# Disabling gsettings keyboard shortcuts in a RHEL systemd service using a bash script

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, systemd

I am writing a screen locking utility using:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6
- Qt Creator
- C++

The user is not supposed to be able to use any keyboard shortcuts while on the lockscreen.

So far I have been able to stop all keyboard shortcuts while debugging in Qt Creator by using the following scripts (using `execute()` in Qt) to disable and then re-enable shortcuts before displaying the login page that is locked:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/bash
shortcuts=$(gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings);
for x in $shortcuts; do
    echo "Disabling $x";
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings $x [];
done
```

The problem arises when I try to execute this script inside my compiled Qt program called using its `PATH` alias from a `systemd` service. The service starts properly and runs the program, and looking at the `journalctl` logs I can see that the `echo "Disabling...` command is being executed, but I am still able to use keyboard shortcuts (by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I can go into `applications->system tools->settings->devices`) and see that nothing has been disabled.

My *testService.service* that I wrote looks like this (don't mind all the commenting as I was doing some experimenting with run `types`):

```bash
[Unit]
Description=testing screenlocker service
After=graphical.target
[Service]
#Type=simple
Type=exec
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
#ExecStartPre=/home/user/Desktop/ScreenLocker/Source/disableShortcuts.sh
ExecStart=/home/user/Desktop/ScreenLocker/Source/build-ScreenLocker-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/Screenlocker
TimeoutStartSec=0
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I am not sure what privilege or setting is keeping this system service from modifying the keymap for the user.

The Qt Code:

main.cpp:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    // set current directory to build directory so QT looks for resources in the right spot
    // (before it would look in the directory above where PWD was and would have issues
    QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());

    // Disabling keyboard shortcuts
    QString qstr = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
    QDir qdir = QDir(qstr);
    qdir.cdUp();
    QString qstrpath = qdir.absoluteFilePath("disableShortcuts.sh");
    qstrpath = QDir::toNativeSeparators(qstrpath);
    system(qPrintable(qstrpath));
...
}
```

mainwindow.cpp, where the logic on the button is stored to reset the shortcuts:

```cpp
void MainWindow::handleButton(){
    QString usr = getUsername();
    QString pswd = getPassword();
    QCloseEvent *event;
    if(usr == "Ray" && pswd == "Theon"){

        // Reenabling keyboard shortcuts
        QString qstr = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
        QDir qdir = QDir(qstr);
        qdir.cdUp();
        QString qstrpath = qdir.absoluteFilePath("resetShortcuts.sh");
        qstrpath = QDir::toNativeSeparators(qstrpath);
        system(qPrintable(qstrpath));

        setStyleSheet("background-color: blue");
        event->setAccepted(true);
        this->close();
    }
}
...
```

Things I have tried:

1. Using `ExecStartPre` / `ExecStopPost` to run the *disableShortcuts.sh* and *resetShortcuts.sh* before and after the screenlocker respectively. I gave this the old college try and couldn't figure it out; if it turns out that it is impossible to do this purely in Qt/bash then I'll revisit this.
2. Using `simple` and `oneshot` in the `type` settings of the .service file in an attempt to keep other services from not preempting the execution of `testService.service` ( you can see in the logs that it gets preempted by the scheduler quite a bit but it does run).
3. Changed the permissions of the bash scripts to 777 so that they won't have any issue with execution permissions by anything/anyone trying to execute them.